# Visually Group the Results of a SELECT Statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to know how to visually group the results of a SELECT statement.

I don't mean the `GROUP BY` clause in which I have the count or sum of similar values.

Let's say I have a table A with columns `CustId, OrderId, Date, Amount` and I do a `SELECT * FROM A ORDER BY CustId, Date`.

I want to see all records, but I want to kind off break with a line, or an empty row each time there is a change in CustId.

Of course I could export to Excel, but...

Thanks!

Comment: Visually group where? In SSMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the practical/helpful answer is "You can't".  It's not common to format your result in sql, assuming you mean like you want row breaks inside Sql Server Management Studio in the results pane. Usually you make visual presentation through separate reporting tools. Crystal Reports, Sql Server Reporting Services.  The thing is, what you see in the results pane is all data. The only way to add "line break" type visual effects in the results pane is to arrange for them to be part of the data.

Maybe there are other clients that have some kind of support for that.  I'm not sure what all you can do with excel by way of formatting when it's connected to a data source, and keeping the connection to the datasource.